# Rails 5: How to make a 'migration partial' in database migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have many tables using the same column names. I want to split them into partials so that I can just edit the partial to change the columns every time I re-create the database.

I've tried:

#### fruit migration file

```
class CreateFruit < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :fruits do |t|
      partial
    end
end
```

#### pet migration file

```
class CreatePet < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :pets do |t|
      partial
      t.string :personality
    end
end
```

#### partial file (application.rb?)

```
def partial
  t.string :name
  t.string :size
end
```

But, I'm always getting a syntax error when running migrations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file named `db/migrate/_partial_migration.rb`:

```
class PartialMigration
  class << self
    def call(t)
      t.string :name
      t.string :size
    end
  end
end
```

In your migration `db/migrate/20180209112447_create_pet.rb`:

```
require_relative "./_partial_migration.rb"

class CreatePet < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :bar do |t|
      PartialMigration.call(t)
      t.string :personality
    end
  end
end
```